# Change position of a field on Access form (Access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in which some fields are hidden depending on an option group selection. So, I'm trying to move some of the fields from the bottom of the form up so that it looks more tidy. Any idea how to do this? I tried the ".Move" method, but all that happens is my buttons and textboxes disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want specific help with the move method, you will have to show us exactly what you are using.

A general sample of how you can use the move method:

```
Private Sub MoveMe_Click()
    MoveMe.Move MoveMe.Left + 10, MoveMe.Top + 10
End Sub
```

This moves the `MoveMe` control 10 twips to the right and to the bottom every time it's clicked.

Note that move uses absolute positioning (e.g. `.Move 10, 10` positions something 10 twips from the top margin of the form, and 10 twips from the left margin of the form).

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you! I had been inputting numbers in inches and also not changing it with respect to the fields original position. This works great.  The MSDN did a poor job of explaining this method :)

Comment: Just a little addendum: Afaik the .Move method uses twips rather than pixel. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip] 1440 Twips = 1 Inch - or 567 Twips = 1cm

Comment: Thanks @ThuroG, I'll edit my answer to include that.